# Syntax for SQL Not In List?

Tags: t-sql, subquery, not-exists

I am trying to develop a T-SQL query to exclude all rows from another table "B".  This other table "B" has 3 columns comprising its PK for a total of 136 rows.  So I want to select all columns from table "A" minus those from table "B".  How do I do this?  I don't think this query is correct because I am still getting a duplicate record error:

```
CREATE TABLE #B (STUDENTID VARCHAR(50), MEASUREDATE SMALLDATETIME, MEASUREID VARCHAR(50))
INSERT #B 
SELECT studentid, measuredate, measureid
  from [J5C_Measures_Sys] 
GROUP BY studentid, measuredate, measureid
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

insert into J5C_MasterMeasures (studentid, measuredate, measureid, rit)
select A.studentid, A.measuredate, B.measurename+' ' +B.LabelName, A.score_14
from [J5C_Measures_Sys] A
join [J5C_ListBoxMeasures_Sys] B on A.MeasureID = B.MeasureID 
  join sysobjects so on so.name = 'J5C_Measures_Sys' AND so.type = 'u'
join syscolumns sc on so.id = sc.id and sc.name = 'score_14' 
join [J5C_MeasureNamesV2_Sys] v on v.Score_field_id = sc.name
 where a.score_14 is not null AND B.MEASURENAME IS NOT NULL
 and (A.studentid NOT IN (SELECT studentid from #B) 
and a.measuredate NOT IN (SELECT measuredate from #B)
and a.measureid NOT IN (SELECT measureid from #B))
```

Answer (score 3):

use `NOT EXISTS`...NOT IN doesn't filter out NULLS

```
insert into J5C_MasterMeasures (studentid, measuredate, measureid, rit)
select A.studentid, A.measuredate, B.measurename+' ' +B.LabelName, A.score_14
from [J5C_Measures_Sys] A
join [J5C_ListBoxMeasures_Sys] B on A.MeasureID = B.MeasureID 
  join sysobjects so on so.name = 'J5C_Measures_Sys' AND so.type = 'u'
join syscolumns sc on so.id = sc.id and sc.name = 'score_14' 
join [J5C_MeasureNamesV2_Sys] v on v.Score_field_id = sc.name
 where a.score_14 is not null AND B.MEASURENAME IS NOT NULL
 AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from  #B where #b.studentid = A.studentid
 and a.measuredate = #B.measuredate
 and a.measureid = #B.measureid)
  and not exists (select 1 from J5C_MasterMeasures z 
                  where z.studentid = A.studentid)
```

Just so you know, take a look at [Select all rows from one table that don't exist in another table](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1#4)

Basically there are at least 5 ways to select all rows from onr table that are not in another table

- NOT IN
- NOT EXISTS
- LEFT and RIGHT JOIN
- OUTER APLY (2005+)
- EXCEPT (2005+)

Comment: Thanks but something about this query is not correct because when I count rows from this query without this NOT EXISTS vs. with it, I am getting same number of rows returned.

Comment: The problem could be that one of those already exists in your J5C_MasterMeasures table..you are right now dumping into #b only the ones with more than 1 row..what if use Test is not in #B but is in [J5C_Measures_Sys] already? you will get a PK violation

Comment: added another not exists clause that filters out the ones already in the J5C_MasterMeasures  table

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general solution for the difference operation using `left join`:

```
select * from FirstTable
left join SecondTable on FirstTable.ID = SecondTable.ID
where SecondTable.ID is null
```

Of course yours would have a more complicated `join on` clause, but the basic operation is the same.

Comment: I tried ur solution also and it was returning same number of rows and duplicate error still.  Do u understand what might be the cause?

Comment: Without more information, no. If you update your question with the exact query you tried that didn't work I can take a look at it and possibly spot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "NOT IN" with a subquery, but you say you have a multi-field key?

I'd be thinking about using a left outer join and then testing for null on the right...

Martin.

Comment: The Not Exists is also a valid approach...

Whilst "NOT IN" is no good to you in your particular case anyway, it is something generally best avoided unless you're dealing with a small set of data in the list you're testing. Behind the scenes the server builds a massive WHERE clause, and there can be limits on the size of that...